# How to find the lim when n goes to infinity of

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, riemann-sum

1) $$\sum_{k=1}^n \ln\left(1+\frac k{n^2}\right) =$$ so I tried solving it with Riemann but I don't know how to do it when I have n squared.(I was thinking of writing it as $$\int_{1}^b\ln(x) $$ .I found that b=2 (probably wrong)).
2)
$$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{n+\sqrt{k+n^2}} =$$ I tried factoring 1/n and I found that the function would be $$\frac{1}{1+\sqrt{x^2+1}}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any $k\in[1,n]$ we have
$$ \log\left(1+\frac{k}{n^2}\right) = \frac{k}{n^2}-\frac{k^2}{2n^4}+O\left(\frac{k^3}{n^6}\right) $$
where
$$ \lim_{n\to +\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{k}{n^2} = \int_{0}^{1}x\,dx = \frac{1}{2} $$
and
$$ \lim_{n\to +\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(\frac{k}{n^2}\right)^{m} = 0 $$
for any $m\geq 2$. In particular, the wanted limit is simply $\color{red}{\large\frac{1}{2}}$.

Comment: Is it okay if I used the fact that $$\\lim_{x\to 0} ln(x+1)/x=0 $$ . I found that the limit is 1/2 but I'm not sure if its okay to approach it this way

Comment: @Lola: $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\log(x+1)}{x}=1\neq 0$. It is equivalent to $\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{z}{e^z-1}=1$ through the substitution $x=e^z-1$, so I wonder *how* you used that incorrect result to prove the given limit equals $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: My bad, I wanted to write =1 and I wrote the sum like this: $$_ [ln(x+1/n^2)/(1/n^2)]*(1/n^2) $$ for every log and in the end I'd have [n(n+1)/2]/n^2 (Sorry for not putting this in LaTeX it's still giving me a hard time.)

Answer (score 2):

Hints:

For 1) use that for $x\geq 0$, you have
$$\frac{x^2}{2}\geq x-\log(1+x)\geq 0$$(replace $x$ by $k/n^2$ and sum)

For 2) use that for $1\leq k\leq n$ you have
$$2n\leq n+\sqrt{k+n^2}\leq n+\sqrt{n+n^2}$$

Comment: how do I know the first inequality?are there some inequalities that need to be learnt?

Comment: To show that $g(x)=x-\log(1+x)\geq 0$ for $x\geq 0$, compute the derivative of $g$ and show that it is $\geq 0$, hence $g$ is increasing and as $g(0)=0$, you are done. Do the same with $h(x)=\log(1+x)-x+x^2/2$.